# Upload content from a BIG CSV to CloudSQL using App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I'm pretty new with Google App Engine.

What i need to do is to upload a pretty large CSV to CloudSQL.
I've got an HTML page that has a file upload module which when uploaded reaches the Blobstore.

After which i open the CSV with the Blob reader and execute each line to CloudSQL using cursor.execute("insert into table values"). The problem here is that i can only execute the HTTP request for a minute and not all the data gets inserted in that short a time. It also keeps the screen in a loading state throughout which i would like to avoid by making the code run in the back end if that's possible?

I also tried going the "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" way.

"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" works from my local machine when i'm connected to CloudSQL via the terminal. And its pretty quick.
How would i go about using this within App Engine?

Or is there a better way to import a large CSV into CloudSQL through the Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage directly after uploading the CSV from the HTML?
Also, is it possible to use Task Queues with Blob Store and then insert the data into CloudSQL on the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a similar approach for Datastore and not CloudSQL but the same approach can be applied to your scenario.

1. Setup a non-default module (previously backend, deprecated now) of your application
2. Send a http request which will trigger the module endpoint through a task queue (to avoid 60 second deadline)
3. Use mapreduce with CSV as input and do the operation on each line of csv within the map function (to avoid memory errors and resume pipeline from where it left in case of any errors during operation)

EDIT: Elaborating map reduce as per OP request, and also eliminating the use of taskqueue

1. Read the mapreduce basics from the docs found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/1-MapReduce)
2. Download the dependency folders for mapreduce to work ([simplejson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/), [graphy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Graphy/1.0.0), [mapreduce](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/tree/master/python/src))
3. Download [this](https://github.com/lucemia/CloudStorageLineInputReader/blob/master/input_readers.py) file to your project folder and save as "custom_input_reader.py"
4. Now copy the code below to your main_app.py file.

**main_app.py**

```
from mapreduce import base_handler
from mapreduce import mapreduce_pipeline
from custom_input_reader import GoogleStorageLineInputReader

def testMapperFunc(row):
    # do process with csv row
    return

class TestGCSReaderPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self):
        yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapPipeline(
            "gcs_csv_reader_job", 
            "main_app.testMapperFunc", 
            "custom_input_reader.GoogleStorageLineInputReader", 
            params={
                "input_reader": { 
                        "file_paths": ['/' + bucketname + '/' + filename]
                    }
            })
```

5. Create a http handler which will initiate the map job

**main_app.py**

```
class BeginUpload(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    # do whatever you want
    upload_task = TestGCSReaderPipeline()
    upload_task.start()
    # do whatever you want
```

6. If you want to pass any parameters, add the parameter in "run" method and provide values when creating the pipeline object

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I've got a lot of reading to do in front of me.
Could you explain a little more about the non-default module part and how i should go about using it?
I read up on task queues right now. That seems pretty doable at the moment. I'll take some time to understand Mapreduce. :s

Comment: @MetalloyD you could do even without modules. I use modules just so the handler is not part of the main application. I will edit my answer to elaborate on the mapreduce part

Comment: Alright, Thanks! :D Btw, is it possible to work with Blobs using Task Queues? I've got an UploadHandler class that takes the CSV import and processes it. I use JINJA2 to put the blobstore.create_upload_url() link for the file upload. Could i use Task Queues within JINJA2?
Because if i call Task Queue from my UploadHandler class, i lose the link to the file. And i can only pass strings in the parameters while making the Task Queue call.
So basically what i'm saying is my JINJA points to /uploadcsv
And my Task Queue is /worker.
If i call /worker from my Upload CSV class, i lose the file link
thx

Comment: @MetalloyD I am not sure if I understand your question entirely. If you are using Blob to store CSV, i suggest you to use GCS and store the csv as simple file as I suggested. On the other point, I don't understand what you mean by losing the link when calling the task queue. Please elaborate and provide edits in the question, so I can help if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing CSV data via cloud console:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export?hl=en#import-csv

Comment: I need to do it through Python though. Programmatically.